# TcpSocket: Обычно разрешается только одно использование адреса сокета

Tags: c#, сокет, tcplistener

Понимаю, что тем с таким заголовком уже уйма, но ответа я так и не увидел. А точнее - что делать в моем случае.

Итак, делаю сервер, который слушает локалку по указанному порту. За основу взял эту библиотеку - https://github.com/nterry/AwesomeSockets.
Вот так выглядит метод запуска прослушивания:

```
public async void StartListening(int port)
{
    if (CancellationTokenSource == null)
        CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _cancellationToken = CancellationTokenSource.Token;
    Clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
    BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Clients, _lockObject);

    try
    {
        while (_tcpListen == null)
        {
            ShowCallbackMessageAction?.Invoke("Try to start server");
            _tcpListen = AweSock.TcpListen(port);

            if (_tcpListen != null)
            {
                ShowCallbackMessageAction?.Invoke("Server started");

                var waitForConnectionTask = Task.Run(() => WaitForConnectionLoop(), _cancellationToken);
                var checkClientsConnectionTask = Task.Run(() => CheckClientsConnectionLoop(), _cancellationToken);

                await Task.WhenAll(waitForConnectionTask, checkClientsConnectionTask);
            }

            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/32768637/4944499
            await Task.Delay(1000, _cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task => { });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ShowCallbackMessageAction?.Invoke($"Error on start server: {exception.Message}");
    }
}
```

Вот так метод остановки прослушивания:

```
public void StopListening()
{
    ShowCallbackMessageAction?.Invoke("Begin stop server...");
    ShowCallbackMessageAction?.Invoke("Disconnect all clients");
    DisconnectAllClients();
    CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    _tcpListen?.Close();
    _tcpListen = null;
    ShowCallbackMessageAction?.Invoke("Server stopped");
}
```

Метод из библиотеки, вызываемый в моем методе StartListening:

```
public static ISocket TcpListen(int port, int backlog = 10)
{
    var listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    //var ip = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    //var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    listenSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
    listenSocket.Listen(backlog);
    return AwesomeSocket.New(listenSocket);
}
```

Так вот - это все работает до того момента, пока я приложение свое не закрою без отписки от прослушивания. Т.е., например, случился крэш. После того, как я повторно запускаю сервер, то вижу сообщение:

[image: Лог из моего приложения]

Везде пишут, что это нормально и порт сам освободится через некоторое время (вроде 240 секунд), но в моем случае этого не происходит. Помогает только перезагрузка компа.
Как быть?

Comment: Посмотрите в диспетчере задач. Не остается ли в процессах ваша программа?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, это в первую очередь смотрел. Нет, не остается. Такое ощущение, что программа закрывается, а статический класс остается работать в памяти ))

Comment: ну такого быть не может, если у вас один домен приложения!

Comment: И почему нельзя воспользоваться стандартными средствами .net?

Comment: @YuryBakharev, мне на другом форуме предположили, что это из-за использования Thread и что поток может остаться в памяти после падения приложения. Да и средства тут все стандартные - просто в той либе все обернуто

Comment: из за использования Thread такого быть не может.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен. Проблема в самом неожиданном месте и, надеюсь, кому-то пригодится.
Итак, используя командную строку и команду

```
netstat -a -b
```

Я выяснил, что порт занимается процессом XDesProc.exe. Погуглив, оказалось, что во всем виноват WPF designer Visual Studio, который пытается имитировать работу окна и тем самым начинает прослушку порта. Просто закрываю редактор xaml и все хорошо становится